# jQuery PrevAll not working with Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason I can't seem to get `prevAll` to work with a select box's option.

What I'm trying to do here is mark all of the options before `omday` as disabled.

Is there a reason JQ ignores it or is there an issue with my code?

This is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var omday = 25;
  $('#inc-day').val(omday);
  $("#inc-day option").prevAll('#inc-day option[value="' + omday + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="incrange" id="inc-day" name="inc-day"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option></select>
```

Comment: What is your goal with that code? `prevAll` doesn't seem to make any sense here.

Comment: its to make them all disabled.

Comment: "them" what? The ones prior to `value=25`?

Comment: Yes. All of the previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly use the selectors to catch actually selected option and then use the `prevAll()` function to disable every `option` element preceding that selected one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var omday = 25;
  $('#inc-day').val(omday);
  $('#inc-day option[value="' + omday + '"]').prevAll().prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="incrange" id="inc-day" name="inc-day"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option></select>
```

Comment: Ah, Thanks.Makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to disable the options prior to the option with the value from the `omday` variable, you need to select that one, then use `prevAll` to get its previous siblings:

```
$('#inc-day option[value="' + omday + '"]').prevAll().prop('disabled', true);
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var omday = 25;
  $('#inc-day').val(omday);
  $('#inc-day option[value="' + omday + '"]').prevAll().prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="incrange" id="inc-day" name="inc-day"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option></select>
```

Your version didn't work because it selected all of the options, then tried to find previous siblings to all of them that had the value from `omday`.